# Satisfying all tests for a Solidity function where a boolean is returned if a value is even

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

This might be a bit of a long one. I've recently started ChainShot's Solidity/Smart Contract intro course, and there's a certain exercise that's driving me up the wall. In this exercise, I have to import a library with a function that finds an even number, like so:

```
library UIntFunctions {
    function isEven(uint x) public pure returns(bool) {
        return (x % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

This is the even function that is to be used for this exercise. **The exercise is as follows:
"We have a contract called Game, you can find it on the new Game.sol tab!
This contract has two state parameters: **participants** and **allowTeams**.
**Your goal is to create a constructor which takes a uint parameter for the number of participants in the game. Store this uint in the participants state variable.**
This game can be played free-for-all or team-against-team. To make sure the teams have the same number, **ensure that the boolean allowTeams is only true if the number of participants is even**."**

Below is the code I have come up with for this exercise:

```
import "./UIntFunctions.sol";

contract Game {
    using UIntFunctions for uint;
    uint public participants;
    bool public allowTeams;

    constructor(uint _participants) {
        participants = _participants;
    }

    function isEven(uint _participants) public returns(bool) {
        if (_participants.isEven()) {
            return allowTeams = true;
        }
        else return allowTeams;
    }
}
```

Now, there are 12 tests that need to be satisfied, of which I manage to satisfy 9 of them. Here is the message I get:

Game

for an even game of 2 participants

✔ should store the number of participants

1. should allow teams

for an even game of 4 participants

✔ should store the number of participants

2. should allow teams

for an even game of 6 participants

✔ should store the number of participants

3. should allow teams

for an odd game of 3 participants

✔ should store the number of participants

✔ should not allow teams

for an odd game of 5 participants

✔ should store the number of participants

✔ should not allow teams

for an odd game of 7 participants

✔ should store the number of participants

✔ should not allow teams

9 passing (2s)

3 failing

As you can see I get through 9 of them, which includes not allowing the teams (e.g. not being even), but I'm unable to get the other 3 tests to validate. I should specify that the IDE I am using is integrated in Chainshot's website, and does not allow me to add any other parameters to the constructor, make another function etc.; just keep it as is and figure it out from there.

Any ideas on how I should fiddle with the code to make all the tests validate? Thanks a lot in advance, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: What are the test you don't pass? Btw, I'll try initializing `allowTeams` to the correct value in the constructor

Comment: The tests that aren't passing are the first three "should allow teams" tests; e.g. returning allowTeams as true. Also the exercise is such that I'm not able to add another parameter to initialize into the constructor without the IDE throwing a validation error. The constructor is only "allowed" to take in one uint parameter for this specific exercise.

Comment: yeah but you can still add logic in the constructor. I wrote an answer, not sure if it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try this:

```
import "./UIntFunctions.sol";

contract Game {
    using UIntFunctions for uint;
    uint public participants;
    bool public allowTeams;

    constructor(uint _participants) {
        participants = _participants;
        allowTeams = _participants.isEven();
    }

    // I don't think this is needed
    function isEven(uint _participants) public returns(bool) {
        if (_participants.isEven()) {
            return allowTeams = true;
        }
        else return allowTeams;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that worked exactly correctly! Guess I did a little too much by including a function when the question didn't explicitly ask me to. Thanks a ton man, this was great!